# How to display the values of database table in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am creating a sample image test where in I want to display all of the images in a database table in CodeIgniter. The question is, how will I able to display the values of the database table using CodeIgniter?

Here is the code of my model:

```
<?php 

    class Image_model extends CI_Model{

        /*Sample test function for the image dropdown list*/
        public function getImages()
        {
            $query = $this->db->select('main_image_url'));
            $this->db->get('product_master');

            return $query->result();
        }
        /*End sample test function*/
    }
 ?>
```

Here is the code of my controller:

```
<?php 
    if(! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Sample_image_dropdown extends MX_Controller{

        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function index()
        {
            $data['main_view'] = 'sample_view/image_dropdown_view';
            $this->load->view('sample_view/image_dropdown_view', $data);
        }

        public function display_all_images()
        {
            $this->load->model('sample_model/image_model');

            $data['images'] = $this->image_model->getImages();

            $data['main_view'] = "sample_view/image_dropdown_view";

            $this->load->view('sample_view/image_dropdown_view', $data);
        }

    }
 ?>
```

Here is the code of my view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <select name="" id="">
            <option value="all">All Image</option>
            <option value="with-image">With Image</option>
            <option value="no-image">Without Image</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </div>
    <?php if (isset($images)):?>

    <?php foreach ($images as $image):?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <th>
                Images
                </th>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="<?php echo "$image->main_image_url";?>">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does `main_image_url` column in the db contain ? Just a link to the image or something else ?

Comment: a link to the image

Comment: `$this->db->select("string");`

Comment: @SherifSalah I tried your suggestion, but it still does not want me to view the data in a table. I also edited the code in my question..

Comment: @ariesdoria hey you load the view in two times $this->load->view('sample_view/image_dropdown_view', $data); . please check that.

Comment: may i know what error you have faced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake in your model and in the controller, I mentioned the changes please note down and try,

Model File

```
class Image_model extends CI_Model{

    /*Sample test function for the image dropdown list*/
    public function getImages()
    {
        $query = $this->db->select('main_image_url');
        $this->db->from('product_master');
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result();
    }
    /*End sample test function*/
}
```

Controller File,

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index()
{
    $data['main_view'] = 'sample_view/image_dropdown_view';
    $this->display_all_images();
}

public function display_all_images()
{
    $this->load->model('sample_model/image_model');    
    $data['images'] = $this->image_model->getImages();    
    $data['main_view'] = "sample_view/image_dropdown_view";    
    $this->load->view('sample_view/image_dropdown_view', $data);
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it worked out. I also tried and call that in my view file like: `<?php foreach($images as $image):?>` `<?php echo "$image->main_image_url";?>`

Comment: hey  @ariesdoria  it's working fine just upvote the answer and close the question.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are storing images in directory at the time of uploading at
`uploads/abc.png`

then you can get data from db (which you are already doing)

and in **view** :

`<img src="echo dir_path./$image->main_image_url;" />`

or if you are storing whole path in **DB** then :

`<img src="echo $image->main_image_url;" />`

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it still does not allow me to view the images. Here is the code I tried: `<img src="<?php echo "$image->main_image_url";?>">`

Comment: can you please show what exactly are you getting in `$image->main_image_url` at any index. also check out without quotes `<?php echo $image->main_image_url;?>`

Comment: I am getting the url of the image that I am doing in `$image->main_image_url`

Comment: try this if you uploaded in directory `<img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/images/'.$image->main_image_url); ?>"/>`

Comment: I tried removing the quotes in the code, just like this: `<img src="<?php echo $image->main_image_url;?>">` but it still does not allow me to view the data in a table..

Comment: what you see if you inspect particularly any image. ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185707/discussion-between-ariesdoria-and-h45h).